# Calling a method through an extended class only works if the Method is overridden java

Tags: java, class, methods, extends, dynamically-generated

i have 4 classes (Core, GameMain, Spriter, Character)
- GameMain extends core (core >> GameMain)
- Character extends Spriter (Spriter >> Character)

I get a **NullPointerException** if i call the - b.get...() - Methods without overriding them in Character (they are originally inside Spriter, i call them from GameMain through Character).

i make objects of Character inside Core and put it in an ArrayList

```
public abstract class Core {
  ArrayList<Character> mon = new ArrayList<Character>();
  void gameloop(){
     while(running){
       //some code
       while(mon.size() < 2){
          mon.add(new Character(blk_1,5,1));// Character(Spriter, Long, Long){}
       }
       draw(g);
     }
  }
}
```

then inside GameMain i call a Method that is originally inside Spriter but i call it through Character.

```
public class GameMain extends Core{
  public  void draw(Graphics2D g){
     for(Character b : mon){ //mon is the ArrayList<Character>

        if(test.getCoordY() <= b.getCoordY() - (b.getHeight()/2)){ //<<<< NullPointerException caused by these two Methods , test is a Spriter class

            g.drawImage(chChange(), Math.round(test.getX()), Math.round(test.getY()), test.getWidth(), (test.getHeight()), null); 
            g.drawImage(b.getImage(), Math.round(b.getX()), Math.round(b.getY()), null);

        }else {
            g.drawImage(b.getImage(), Math.round(b.getX()), Math.round(b.getY()), null);
            g.drawImage(chChange(), Math.round(test.getX()), Math.round(test.getY()), null);
        }
     } 
   }
}
```

Here is the Spriter's Method, unless i override it i will get the error.

```
public class Spriter {
   Spriter(Image i){
      this.i = i;
      scenes = new ArrayList();

   }

   Spriter(){
      scenes = new ArrayList();
      start();
   }

   public int getHeight(){
    return i.getHeight(null);
   }
   public float getCoordY(){
      float cy;
      cy = y + i.getHeight(null); //<<<< NullPointerException happens here, Image i;
      return cy;
   }

   public void setX(float x){
    this.x = x;
   }

   public void setY(float y){
    this.y = y;
   }
   // other similar Methods but no problem with them
   //-------------------------------------- Animation Part ----------------------------------------------

public synchronized void addScene(Image i,long t){
    total_t+=t;
    scenes.add(new oneScene(i, total_t));
}

//start animation
public synchronized void start(){
    mov_time = 0;
    scn_indx = 0;
}

    // get current scene
public synchronized Image getAnimeImage(){
    if(scenes.size()==0){
        return null;
    }else{
        return getScene(scn_indx).pic;
    }
}


//get the scene
private oneScene getScene(int x){
    return (oneScene)scenes.get(x);
}


 private class oneScene{
    Image pic;
    long endTime;

    public oneScene(Image pic, long endTime){
        this.pic = pic;
        this.endTime = endTime;

    }
}
}
```

it would work if i do this :

```
public class Character extends Spriter{
  public Character(Spriter s, long health, long power) {
     this.s = s;
     this.health = health;
     this.power = power;

     s.setX(randomY());
     s.setY(randomY());
  }

  public float getCoordY(){
     return s.getCoordY();
  }

  public float getHeight(){
     return s.getgetHeight();
  }
  //some other methods for health and power 
}
```

but can it work if i do this (it is already givinng the error but how to avoid it) :

```
public class Character extends Spriter{
  public Character(Spriter s, long health, long power) {
      this.s = s;
      this.health = health;
      this.power = power;

      s.setX(randomY()); //setting x for the dynamiclly generated Character Object
      s.setY(randomY()); // same for y
  }

  //some methods for power and health
}
```

as setting x,y for test (its a sprite and working very good)

```
public class GameMain extends Core{
  public void init(){
    test.setX(500); test.setY(488);
  }

  public  void draw(Graphics2D g){
    //the above code
  }
}
```

i dont see the point of overriding them if they will be exactly the same.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the exception, or are you asking how to design you classes and whether to override?  in either case, you need to show all relevant code, not bits and peices that require guesswork to fill in the deyails.

Comment: What is `i` and where is the code that sets it?

Comment: @atk the error wont appear if i override ... so iam asking why do i have to override and if there is something wrong that leads to this

Comment: We can't tell unless you show us your code and be more specific about where the NPE happens.

Comment: @Sotirios, He's indicated where it happens.  I reckon he's got a field duplicated between two of the classes, and he's setting one copy and dereferencing the other.  But that would just be a guess - which is why I asked my question.

Comment: Where do you set the x and y coordinates?

Comment: @atk in the Character's Constructor  -at- David 'i' is an Image

Comment: @atk i will update the code above

Comment: Your works and doesn't work code are identical.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes but only the override one is working

Comment: @OmAr Please make your problem statement clearer, because I can't understand what you're trying to demonstrate.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch done , and the problem is that i have to override the method to get rid of the NPE error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you create a `Character`, you're calling the no-arg constructor of `Spriter`, instead of the one with an `Image` argument.  That means that your image is never getting set; which is why you have the null pointer exception.

You should probably add an `Image` to the constructor arguments of `Character`, and pass this along to the superclass constructor, like this.

```
public Character(Spriter s, long health, long power, Image img) {
    super(img);

    // and so on.
```

@ElliottFrisch - I apologise if that is what you were trying to say with your answer.  I don't mean to duplicate; I just wasn't quite sure whether that is what you meant.  In any case, this is definitely the problem.

Comment: tried it with `mon.add(new Character(test,5,1));` and `mon.add(new Character(new Spriter(monster_pic),5,1));` but its the same

Comment: The snippets in your comment here suggest that you didn't take my advice at all.  If you had changed the `Character` constructor, those two wouldn't compile.

Comment: i replace `Spriter s` by `Image img` or do i keep it ... i dont see the use of `Spriter s` if i have `img` passed to `super` , plus will the image keep its animation(spriting)

Comment: @DavidWallace When I answered there was no code... at this point I'm not sure what he's tried or not.

Comment: Read my code, and do what I suggested.  All of your existing constructor will stay - you'll just have one more parameter, and one extra line at the top.

Comment: it worked !thanks ...@ElliottFrisch but 2 things here how can i animate the character if iam passing 1 img , i did that `mon.add(new Character(test,5,1,monster_pic1));` ... other thing is test here (which is the moving character) is not showing and if i remove it the code wont work ... iam confused O.o

Comment: But you're not getting a null pointer exception any more, right?  What you're asking now is how to do animation?  That's a completely different question, and one which you're unlikely to get an answer to on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes no more NPE , it was animating before i try to dynamically generate monsters (it was 6-7 images passed to the `ArrayList` in `Spriter` and the `update()` Method -its not in the code posted- changes between them and then they are given to `draw(g)`)

Comment: the idea was to give an already animated spriter health and power while they are created dynamically

Comment: @DavidWallace also this worked `public Character(Spriter s, long health, long power) {
  super(s.getAnimeImage()); }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that your class `Character` is-a `Spriter` and has-a `Spriter` (and probably shouldn't "have-a" `Spriter` but I can't tell because you didn't post all of your code). You never initialized the `super` instance of your `Character`.

```
public class Character extends Spriter{
  public Character(Spriter s, long health, long power) {
    // super(health, power); // <-- Speculation, no constructors shown in your code.
    this.s = s;
    this.health = health;
    this.power = power;

    super.setX(randomY()); //<-- set the super value
    super.setY(randomY()); //<-- again.
    // s.setX() // <-- not sure, why do you have s?
  }
```

Comment: sorry for that iam sleepy and cant think straight ... i will post more code now , as for the `s` i use it to identify the incoming sprite like if its a monster or a boss not for me but for the draw(g)

Comment: @OmAr Sounds like it should be a Sprite... not have one.

Comment: you mean i delete the Character class?

Comment: @OmAr I mean remove the `Sprite s` instance from the `Character` class (you can save some state from one in the constructor if you need) or you can continue to "Decorate" it... it's really your call.

Comment: if i remove the `Spriter s` then how the `g.drawImage` is going to get the Image in the line :`g.drawImage(b.getImage(), Math.round(b.getX()), Math.round(b.getY()), null);`

Comment: There's still the "super" Spriter.

Comment: iam not sure i get you but i made everything `super.` in Character still nothing ... i tried @david 's suggetion by adding img and passing it to super , it worked but with 2 logical or other problems

Comment: And what were those "logical or other problems"?